When linking Google login, sometimes a consent pop-up appears and sometimes it does not
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
.requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId)
.requestEmail()
.build();
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(LoginActivity.this, gso);

When executing the following Google login linking code, the consent pop-up may or may not appear. It appears about 70% of the time, and about 30% of the time it does not appear. All tests were conducted with Google login linkage turned off before proceeding with the linkage process.
Whether the consent pop-up appears or not, linking to your Google account works fine. However, I am curious about the difference or reason when the consent pop-up appears and when it does not appear.
